# Re-prompting users after invalid input

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm setting up a reset password intent using Dialogflow, where I'm performing some validation via webhooks. Unfortunately, I'm not able to figure out how to reprompt the user in case of failed validation.

I've tried to trigger the intent again using an event, but it doesn't seem to be working. I've also tried setting the same input contexts to trigger the intent again, but neither seem to work.

So I've created 2 parameters within the intent, which are being filled via prompts, following which I am performing the validation. Here's the code:

```
function getPasscode(agent) {
  console.log(agent.parameters);
  if(/^\d{6}$/.test(agent.parameters.code1) && agent.parameters.code1 == agent.parameters.code2) {
    // Reset passcode call
  } else {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      agent.add("Your codes don't match. Please try again.");
      var output = JSON.stringify({"followupEvent": {"name": "GetPasscode", "data": {}}})
      resolve(output);
    });
  }
}
```

The bot outputs the text properly, but isn't triggering the event, as intended.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

Remember that Intents *represent what the user does* and *not* what your action is trying to do. In general, you don't "trigger" an Intent - the user does.

So if you're "reprompting" the user - send that prompt in your reply to them. Then make sure the Intent is setup to capture their reply. This may involve in your setting an Output Context to narrow which Intents are evaluated to consider the reply.

You can't both send back a response *and* trigger an Intent with an event. Sending an event from your fulfillment is almost never needed and, when done, discards anything you may already have set for a response. All it does is cause the Intent with the event registered to it to be triggered. (Your code has two problems in this respect - you both try to send a response, and you're trying to send the followup event incorrectly.)

Comment: I understand that, but events are used to trigger intents, with the necessary parameters right?
So can't I call an event itself to re-prompt?

Comment: Intents don't "prompt" - they respond. In theory, you can trigger an event which would send the reply that an Intent does - but this doesn't mean "wait for the user to say something". I clarified my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

In your use-case, you do not need to call the event as per my understanding. Better way to do this is :

- Set-up intent where you ask and confirm the password and store it
- Validate this in your webhook

Here is the pseudo code:

```
if validationPassed {
    call your api to reset password
    send reset password confirmation output to user
} 
if validationFailed {
    setup output context to ask-password intent again
    send output to user to re-enter the password
}
```

As @Prisoner says, you do not trigger an intent, the user does. We do the processing and send the response once the intent is triggered.
Hope it helps.